# I can't quite wrap my head around these two functions

Tags: python

These two function ares in my Python programming book, and I just can't quite get why they're doing what they're doing. I really wanna understand, so any explanation would be great.

```
def example(aString, index):
    if index == len(aString):
        return ""
    else:
        return aString[index] + example(aString, index + 1)
```

and...

```
def example(aString, index):
    if index < len(aString):
        example(aString, index +1)
        print(aString[index], end="")
```

Comment: By the way, they're not doing anything wrong, I just want to understand how they work.

Comment: Please indent them properly.

Comment: Did you try running them, or changing them or anything that required analysing the code?

Answer (score 0):

**First example**, returns the string as it is.

```
def example(aString, index):
    if index == len(aString):
        return ""
    else:
        return aString[index] + example(aString, index + 1)
```

Lets say, this function is invoked like this

```
example("abc", 0)
```

The first if condition checks if the index has gone beyond the length of the string. If that is the case, it simply returns an empty string. Otherwise, it picks up the current character at position `index` and calls the same function with the next index `index + 1`. This is called **recursion**. So it will be evaluated like this

```
"a" + example("abc", 1)
"a" + ("b" + example("abc", 2))
"a" + ("b" + ("c" + example("abc", 3)))
"a" + ("b" + ("c" + ""))
```

So the actual output is `abc`.

But for example,

```
example("abc", 1)
```

will return `bc`. This behavior is called **slicing**. Thanks to kojiro for pointing it out.

**Second example**, just prints the reversed string, character by character.

```
def example(aString, index):
    if index < len(aString):
        example(aString, index +1)
        print(aString[index], end="")
```

This is another recursion based solution. Lets say, this function is also invoked like this

```
example("abc", 0)
```

The `if` check makes sure that we don't go beyond the length of the string. If the condition evaluates to Truthy value, then we immediately call the same function (**recursion**) with the next index. This will continue until we reach the end of the string. When we reach the end of the string, we ll return from the function to the function which called. When we reach the function which called, the index will be `2`. So, it will print `c` and we return back from there to the function which called it, it will have index 1, so it will print `b`. This way it reverses the string.

The same way as the first example, we can get only last few characters of the string reversed with the second example like this.

```
example("Welcome", 3)
```

will print

```
emoc
```

Comment: The first example doesn't just return the string as-is. It also does super-expensive slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Example one is equivalent to calling the slice operation and specifying the start to be the given index.

For example:

```
>>> 'abcde'[2:] == example('abcde', 2)
True
```

To see this, take note of how the function works. It first checks to see if the index is valid by checking it against the length of the string. Then if the index is valid, it returns the character at that index prefixed to the return value of the recursive call. The recursive call is the same as the original call, but it increases the index by 1. This happens until the function reaches the **base case** at which point, it will cease to make recursive calls and simply return its base value, the empty string.

Note that you could still easily get an IndexError with example one...All you have to do is give it a negative index or an index greater than the length of your string.

---

The second example prints the characters of your string in reverse order up to the given index. Note that the recursive calls which call it for the `index+1` element are forced to return before the current call. This means that the print statements for the recursive calls will be executed *before* the print statements for the current call.

Maybe an example would help you to visualize the recursion.

Let's say your string is `'abcde'` You make the call `example('abcde', 3)`.

Since 3 is less than the length of the string, it will make a recursive call: `example('abcde', 4)`

Since 4 is less than the length of the string, it will make *another* recursive call: `example('abcde', 5)`. However for this call, your index will not be less than the length of the string (the length of the string is 5) so the function will just return without printing anything. Now that the function has returned, we are back at the call: `example('abcde', 4)`. Now it can print the character at index 4, which is 'e'. Then that function will return and we will return to the call `example('abcde', 3)`. It will print the character at index 3, which is 'd'.

Finally your original call to the function will return after having printed 'ed'.